# Generate OAS3 API from AWS serverless YAML without deploying?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, openapi, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am developing a moderately complex (for me) serverless infrastructure on AWS that consists of about 50 lambdas and would like to start fleshing out the API documentation but am finding it very tedious. Right now any time I want to make a minor schema change, documentation change, etc. in my YAML, I am re-deploying the whole Cloud Formation and then regenerating the OAS3 API with

```
sls deploy
aws apigateway get-export --parameters extensions='apigateway' \
--rest-api-id $API_ID --stage-name dev --export-type oas30 \
latest_changes.json
```

This is obviously pretty time consuming and I feel like there must be a better way. I poked around with with [serverless-documentation](https://wb.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-openapi-documentation) plugin, but that still seems to require a redeploy (and only works with OAS2), and I've now started investigating `serverless-offline` (which I wish I knew about in the past), but before I go down that rabbit hole I wanted to see if there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I was ultimately able to do what I want using the [serverless-openapi](https://github.com/theodo/serverless-openapi) plugin (I'm actually using [the pvdlg fork](https://github.com/pvdlg/serverless-openapi)), which uses a custom:documentation style very similar to the OAS2 serverless-aws-documentation plugin from serverless.com. With that plugin installed I can then do `sls openapi generate -f json -o oas3api.json` to output swagger that's *pretty* close to fully documented, though I did have to write a small script to ingest the swagger, add in per-path security sections (which the plugin doesn't seem to support) and an `info` block for things like a contact name and TOS, and spit it back out again.

But at least it means no more waiting for AWS to update the CloudFormation just so I can update my docs!